# How can I specify different config files in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, configuration-files

```
try
    config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'ascii'))
catch e
    util.debug("Could not parse configuration file.\n" + e.stack)
    return
```

I have that in my `node.js` code and I have two config files"

- config.json.prod
- config.json.local

How can I specify that it should run the `.local`?

By the way, I'm using `CoffeeScript`

Comment: `./config.json.local` read that one.

Comment: How do you want to call it? You could try symlinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, you certainly can. Checkout nodepad (great reference app):

https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js

The source comes from this blog series: http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/

*Edit*: For example

```
if (app.settings.env == 'production') {
    mailer.send(mailOptions,
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

> he uses app.settings.env to swap out different environmental/app settings. Same could be used to load a config file. – Chance

Comment: @Chance I didn't downvote, but it was probably because 'Yea, you certainly can' followed by a random link doesn't _really_ answer the question. The FAQ says `If you see misinformation, vote it down.` Just providing a link without an explanation (lack of information) can be considered misinformation.

Comment: @JimSchubert That's fair. My whole gripe was that if you down vote someone, you should provide a reason in the comments. Had whomever downvoted me done that, I would have added the edit that you did for me :)

Comment: @Chance I completely agree with your gripe.  Too many people downvote for no good reason.  I personally think answers that guide the question toward a solution are correct and useful answers. I'd bet most downvotes occur because the user doesn't fully understand the question... just like real-life arguments at work!